# Why repaint doesn't call to paintComponent function?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, repaint

this code is part of client. the part of getting information from the server is working, but it's not calling to repaint function (line 6).

```
public class Client extends JPanel implements Runnable{


public Client() throws IOException{  
        f = new JFrame("Bad Ice Cream by - Rotem Hanoch");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(this.width,this.height);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setFocusable(false);
        f.setVisible(true);
        initBoard();
        f.add(this);
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try {
                Board.Type mat[][] = (Board.Type[][]) this.objectInputStream.readObject();
                updateBoard(mat);
                this.repaint();
            } catch (IOException ex) {} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {}
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

I tried to figure out why it doesn't work because it doesn't recognize the function. I expect it to print me a message so I know it has reached the function.

Comment: note: you _must not_ change a component off the EDT! It's not entirely clear whether you do (repaint is safe), but if updateBoard changes the ui in any other way you might be in trouble. Also: don't swallow exceptions, instead handle or at the very least print its stacktrace to be able to get a hint of what's wrong.

Comment: as to your problem: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Components need to be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible. Otherwise, the layout manager is not invoked and the component has a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

Comment: thank you the problem solved, I didn't notice I forgot to increase size.